# how can i implement this Type in typescript?

Tags: typescript-typings

```
type NeedImplement<T,K extends 'key1' | 'key2'> = {
    code: string
    K: T
}

// example should be work
const type1:NeedImplement<number,'key1'> = {
    code: '1',
    key1: 123
}
```

Q1:How can i implement this?

Q2:If the default key is 'key1',what else need todo?

Thank you !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You have to use two TypeScript features: [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and type intersection.

```ts
type NeedImplement<T, Keys extends 'key1' | 'key2'> = {
    [key in Keys]: T
} & {
    code: string
}

const type1: NeedImplement<number,'key1'> = {
    code: '1',
    key1: 123
}
```

Note that you have to use a type intersection because you cannot add properties to a mapped type.

Comment: @linct
I am glad this was helpful. Could you resolve the question? Have a nice day!